# Rog Phone wont connect to internet with data but wifi, calls, and texts work fine

Tags: mobile-data, 9.0-pie, 4g

my phone is not able to use the internet on data, but wifi works fine. I can still send and recieve texts, and phone calls work too but it's just the data. My sim works fine because I've tested it on another phone. My phone is an Asus Rog phone (1, 512GB, Android Pie) and is not locked to any carrier.
Please inform of any possible fixes

Thanks